# htaccess mod_headers for no-caching

Tags: apache, jsp, caching, http-headers, mod-headers

We have an application that allows users to add/edit/replace/delete content (text, images, swfs, mp3s, etc).  We want the admins to always have the latest updated files by using a no-cache header and when a user runs the application, everything gets/uses the cache.

I have looked into solutions and have tried using html meta tags like:

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

But that doesn't seem to be a good solution as this happens after the headers are created and doesn't change the media (images, swfs, mp3s, etc) headers.

I wanted to use apache to set the headers and came across this code for [this site](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html):

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

This seems to be a great solution, however the only real difference between when we need it cached and when it shouldn't be cached is the URL (preview.jsp vs run.jsp), so we can't match it by file type as most files are the same.

Does anyone have a good solution for this type of scenario?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Preview.jsp and run.jsp basically are the same only with different jsp and js processing.  They read in the same content and media through an iframe.  For example, they each look like:

```
<%
//Some JSP
%>
/* HTML Headers, JS, ETC */
<iframe id="contentFrame" seamless="1" src="http://somedomain.com/template.html"></iframe>
/* End HTML */
```

preview.jsp and run.jsp appear in the same directory and use all the same resources.  I am looking for a solution to have preview.jsp not to cache anything and run.jsp to cache things.

Server is setup with Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of [`SetEnvIf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) and [`Header`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) might do the trick:

```
# Image, CSS and JavaScript requests normally contain the Referer header
# which tells apache which page is requesting the resource
# Use SetEnvIf directive to set a flag for internal uses

SetEnvIf Referer preview\.jsp force_no_cache

# Header directive optionally accepts env= argument
# If present, the directive is fired if the flag is set

Header unset ETag env=force_no_cache

# repeat for other headers
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this will work.  I will try it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up corresponding headers in your Java servlet. Apache mod_headers is mostly supposed to work for static resources, managed by Apache. While everything that is provided by application servers is managed on the AS side.

Usually, you can use Filters for this purpose. Here is an example: http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/11/adding-headers-to-requests-in-filters.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am fairly new to jsp, so please bare with me. Does setting the headers this way affect all media within the page? Is that why you would go this route instead of a simple "response.setHeader"?

Comment: response.setHeader affects only contents provided by a JSP/Servlet. Media resources may (and should) have different caching settings. So basically, you use Apache for static resources with its own set of settings, and Java app sets caching headers only for content provided by JSP (i.e. contents of a page, not media)

Comment: My main issue is the caching of media (images, mp3's, swf's), but because in some scenarios I need them cached (production) and other scenarios I need them not to be cached (development), how would I go about doing this?

Comment: I simply have different configuration files for different environments. If you have a single Apache for both, then you can distinguish them by URL (e.g. dev urls starts from /dev like /images/a.png and /dev/images/a.png). It's not necessarily to have different folders with images - you can simply use Apache Rewrite to point them to the same directory.

Comment: The thing is, its the same environment and the same url.  So somedomain.com/preview.jsp and somedomain.com/run.jsp both are setup the same, only with different processing. They each have an iframe that has somedomain.com/template.html in it for example that might have somedomain.com/image/1.jpg and somedomain.com/image/2.jpg. Are you saying to change the url of all preview media and links to another directory and use apache to set to not cache and redirect back to same directory? What happens in the iframe of those templates? Do you have any working samples to help get on the right track?

Comment: So your jsps just return something like `<iframe src=""...` and that is it?

Comment: Please describe your situation in the question so I can figure out better what you need. I.e. what JSPs, what env. etc.

Comment: I added to the question.  Let me know if this gives you enough information.  Thanks.