# Tomcat config for no-cache media

Tags: jsp, tomcat, no-cache

I basically need a solution for Tomcat with the same information as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078168/htaccess-mod-headers-for-no-caching/) question I posted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a filter or a server-side valve which adds these headers or even wraps the response and adds these headers in any case.

Comment: Will that cover all media in a given page based on the parameters?

Comment: If you examine the path and add the headers, yes.